# How to show negative entropy function $f(x)=x\log(x)$ is strongly convex?

Tags: inequality, logarithms, convex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=x\log(x)$. How to show it is strongly convex, i.e.,

*Definition*: Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Then $f$ is strongly convex if $\exists$ a positive constant $\alpha > 0$ such that 
$$
 \langle \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x),y-x  \rangle \geq \alpha||y-x||^2 \,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n \tag{1}
$$
Following $(1)$ we have $(y-x)\log(\frac{y}{x})\geq \alpha(y-x)^2 
\,\,\,\,\,
\forall x,y  \in \mathbb{R}_+$.

What $\alpha$ satisfies the above and how we can handle the inequality $\forall x,y  \in \mathbb{R}_+$ ?

Comment: Why don't you calculate the second derivative?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner : Because I want to better understand the definition to proof the general case:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3055187/how-to-show-negative-entropy-function-rx-sum-i-1nx-i-logx-i-is-strongl and solve it.

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner : Also, the second derivative does not specify $\alpha$. Actually, I do not know how to use this fact saying strongly convex implies $\nabla^2f(x) \succeq \alpha I$ for this case to get $\alpha$.

Comment: The case $x=1,\,y=1+z>0$ gives $\frac{\ln(1+z)}{z}\ge\alpha$, which for sufficiently large $z>0$ contradicts any proposed $\alpha>0$.

Comment: @J.G. : I think I should have assumed that $0 \leq x \leq 1$?

Comment: @J.G. : Great observation! That means if I want to have the result in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for negative entropy, I need to assume that $\|x\|_{\infty}$ must be bounded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $f'(x)=1+\log(x)$. Strong convexity therefore means that there exists a strictly positive $\alpha$ such that
$$[\log(y)-\log(x)](y-x)\geq\alpha(y-x)^2$$
holds. Without loss of generality I assume $y>x$. Then the above inequality requires that
$$\log(y)-\log(x)\geq\alpha(y-x).$$
Although you don't state it, I assume that the variables $x$ and $y$ live on $(0,1)$ (because they are probabilities). Since the slope of the $\log$ function on the interval $(0,1)$ is larger than or equal to 1, you can choose any positive $\alpha$ smaller than 1.

If $x$ and $y$ live on a general bounded interval $(0,M)$, then the argument goes through with $\alpha<1/M$.

Comment: I understand the argument justifying $\log(y)-\log(x)\geq\alpha(y-x)$ but could you show it algebraically?

Comment: @Saeed: $\log$ is concave. Hence, $\log(x)\leq\log(y)+(1/y)(x-y)$. Since $1/y\geq1/M$, one gets $\log(y)-\log(x)\geq(1/y)(y-x)\geq(1/M)(y-x)$.

Comment: Smart way of showing that.