# Name and/or notation for the function $x \log_b x$

Tags: notation, terminology

I am using a lot the function $$x \log_b(x),\quad \text{for } x \in [0,1].$$

The base $b$ is mostly $2$ but not only.

Is there a special name or more-or-less standard notation for this function? I googled but cannot find anything. Perhaps, I just don't know how to formulate my search query.

Comment: The way you wrote it is the best way.

Comment: It becomes a bit more tricky/ugly when $x$ is a large expression :)

Comment: Well, in that case, you could always just let a new variable $z$ be the complicated expression, at least for intermediate calculations.

Comment: I agree with Adrian. You could define, say, $$f(x) = x \log_b(x)$$ and use that definition. You could alternatively do similar for $x$ itself depending on the nature of the expression.

Comment: Some people call it the ["negative entropy function"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3077287) (explanation you must know coming from information theory)

Comment: Never heard of negentropy before :) Need to check that. Although I don't see any nice notation so far...